# How to create stack bar chart using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data-set as below:

```
A   B   C
1   1   1
0   1   1
1   0   1
1   0   1
```

I want to have a stack bar chart that shows percentage of 1 and 0 in each column next to other column all in one figure.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far and where you get stuck.

Answer (score 3):

There are several steps you need to take:

- calculate how many zeros and ones are for each variable
- calculate relative percentage (you don't define this in your question
- reflow data from wide to long (use `tidyr::gather`)
- plot using `ggplot`'s [`geom_bar`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to tidy your data

```
library(tidyr)

A = c(1,0,1,1)
B = c(1,1,0,0)
C = c(1,1,1,1)

data = data.frame(A,B,C)
data = gather(data, key = type, value = val)
```

Then compute your statistics

```
library(dplyr)
perc = group_by(data, type) %>% summarise(perc = sum(val)/length(val))
```

To finish plot them

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(perc) + aes(x = type, y = perc) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```